# Can't acces apache on docker from my network

Tags: docker, apache2

I have this Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
EXPOSE 80
```

After installing apache2 package in the container I can't acces the default page of apache from the network. Also docker is in a virtual machine with debian 10. If I try the official apache image (https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd) everything works fine but I want to know why installing it manually doesn't work.

To build the container from the image I use this command :

```
sudo docker run --name ubuntu -p 80:80 -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: Nothing that you've shown installs Apache: you're only running an interactive shell in an unmodified Ubuntu image.  Usually you wouldn't run either the base `ubuntu` image (instead run a custom image with your software preinstalled) or `bash` as the main container command (directly run something like `apachectl -DFOREGROUND` to make the HTTP server be the main container process).

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, sorry about that, the commands I used are in the accepted answear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run the exactly same test on my virtual centos machine and found working.

I've build the image using your dockerfile and run apache installation using below command.

```
docker build -t ubuntu
docker run --name ubuntu -p 80:80 -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

and In terminal opened by the above mentioned command, i ran the below command.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install apache2
service apache2 start
```

After that opened another ssh terminal keeping the current running as i have not run the Ubuntu container in detached mode and checked by using.

```
docker ps -a
```

and found container is running with exposing 0.0.0.0:80 and checked

```
curl localhost
```

**Please make sure you have not stoped docker container before running curl command or hit in the browser as its not run in detached mode or background.**

Comment: The problem was that I didn't run service apache2 start , thank you